# getting data from mysql showing empty string

Tags: php, mysql

I fetch data from mysql and convert it to JSON but receive an empty array as a result: `[]`

I want to select all data where category=given variable:

```
$flu = $_POST['searchCode'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * From catalog_Master WHERE  category='%$flu%'");

$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Have you tryed running that query directly on your MySQL client?

Comment: make sure you are getting records from your query.

Comment: You are not doing any error checking.

Comment: Are you sure your query returns any data can you do a var_dump($query)

Comment: Is there any category in your table with name %$flu%? If your intention is like query, the use category like '%$flu%'

Comment: @Jocelyn i have not added full code i have done all error checking also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `%` to work in MySQL, you need [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html):

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * From catalog_Master WHERE category LIKE '%$flu%'");
```

You can also match beginning or end:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * From catalog_Master WHERE category LIKE '$flu%'");
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * From catalog_Master WHERE category LIKE '%$flu'");
```

If you want exact matches, lose the `%` and the `LIKE`:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * From catalog_Master WHERE category='$flu'");
```

Also, you should validate your `$_POST` variables (at least use `mysql_real_escape_string`, better use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)).

Comment: No problem. Be sure to read up on the MySQL documentation ;-).

Comment: but it getting all values if flu has Category 1 then it also fetches Category 2 Category 3 also i want that if flu has Category 1 then it should only fetch Category 1 not the other starting with category

Comment: @ShahzadAli in that case, you don't need `LIKE`, and you also don't need `%`. I updated my answer.

Comment: can answer my comment please

Comment: but in this it is not showing any thing again and in data base it is present  NSString*searchText=@"Category 1";

Comment: using the new withoud like it showing [] again this in the browser while testing

Comment: can you please answer that why it is showing again []

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query =mysql_query("SELECT * From catalog_Master WHERE  category like '".$flu."%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$flu = $_POST['searchCode'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * From catalog_Master WHERE  category LIKE '%".$flu.%"'");

$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```